# returning undefined after Firebase get request

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a userService Module:

```
class UserService {
    constructor(reference) {
        this.usersRef = reference;
    }

    async getUser(uid) {
        let docs;
        await this.usersRef.where('uid', '==', uid).get()
        .then(result => {
            result.forEach(doc => {
                return doc.data();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And I got this route that calls the getUser(uid) function in the service:

```
router.route('/mp3').post((req, res) => {
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './files/',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "test" + ".mp3");
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();
upload(req, res, async (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    } else {

       let user = userService.getUser('AhtlOSge59bGGuKd43dEjUgt7Di4');

       user.then(function(result) {
        // this is undefined
        console.log(result)
       });
    }
});
```

});

So in the second Code-Block I'm trying to log the result of calling getUser(uid) but it seems to be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return doc.data()` statement isn't actual returning anything to the caller of `getUser`.  `getUser` currently returns a promise that always resolves to `undefined` because `getUser` never returns an actual value.  (Also, your `docs` variable doesn't do anything - it never gets used.)

Notice that your return statement only returns a value to the anonymous function that you passed to `forEach`.  That return value doesn't escape that tiny function.  If you want to return the first document that matches the query, you'll need to arrange to return it from `getUser` directly by fetching it out of the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

```
    async getUser(uid) {
        const snapshot = await this.usersRef.where('uid', '==', uid).get()
        if (snapshot.size > 0) {
            return snapshot.docs[0].data();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the explanation, clears many things up since I'm pretty new to Node & Firebase! :)